# How to show/represent an ionic bond visually?

Tags: bond

How to represent/ show an ionic bond visually?
For example in NaCl

Answer (score 3):

Some examples are as follows, 
$$
\ce{[Na]+ [Cl]-} \, , \\
\ce{[Mg]^2+ 2[Cl]-} \, , \\
\ce{3[Mg]^2+ 2[N]^3-} \, .
$$
Hopefully you get the idea, so a general rule is:
$$
\text{#ions}[\text{element symbol}]^{\text{magnitude of cation charge}} \text{#ions}[\text{element symbol}]^{\text{magnitude of anion charge}} \, .
$$

Comment: I appreciate your answer but my concern is how to represent in 3D model. Let's say Sodium acetate,the ionic bond between Na+ and O- .You may refer jmol for 3D models.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning the depiction of ionic bonds,  the [*Graphical Representation Standards for Chemical Structure Diagrams* (IUPAC Recommendations 2008)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020277) read as follows:

> Structures that are known to be ionic should be depicted as such. They should be drawn with atoms bearing explicit positive and negative charges, and there should be a space (rather than a bond) between those atoms.
>
> [image: depiction of ionic bonds]

Comment: I think you should expand the quote to include some points from the next section "GR-7.2 Positioning of components" as well, namely: 1) that there are two ways to position components and 2) what is the recommended way of drawing salts with more than two components.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but my concern is how to represent in 3D model. Let's say Sodium acetate,the ionic bond between Na+ and O- .You may refer jmol for 3D models.